# Horizontal glue with bigfoot para style

Tags: footnotes, bigfoot, glue

How can I make the horizontal strechability between the footnotes infinite, so that they become evenly aligned at the right margin?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\textheight=.4\textheight

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}

\begin{document}
All of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The easy solution is to end every footnote with \hfill\null.

Answer (score 1):

This performs the `\hfill\null` operation automatically.

Without the `\null` the `\hfill` is absorbed by the `\vbox` which stores the footnote.  Alas, with the `\null` the right edges are not aligned.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\textheight=.4\textheight

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}

\let\oldfootnote=\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{#1\hfill\null}}

\begin{document}
All of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

If you really want them to form nice columns, you should use `\makebox`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\textheight=.4\textheight

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}

\let\oldfootnote=\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{\sbox0{\footnotemark}%
  \makebox[\dimexpr 0.24\textwidth-\wd0][l]{#1}}}

\begin{document}
All of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo2]

Comment: Thanks! but the right margin isn't quite even.

Comment: Could you please explain why the `\null` is necessary?

Comment: Each footnote is stored in a \vbox.  Bigfoot uses \unvbox and \nointerlineskip to merge them together, then formats them as a single paragraph.

Comment: Do you know why the right margin is uneven? I think it has something to do with the width of the footnote number (10, 11, 12 are wider than single digits are).

Comment: Each \hfill expands to the same size, therefore the more text the smaller each gap.  Since there is an \hfill at the end of the line, that gap also changes size.

Comment: Oh I see. Then there should not be an `\hfill` at the end of the line.

Comment: I think the problem is that even with the `\makebox`, the right margin is not exactly even (just as in the first image). The first line (with the “7” footnote) has its `.` a bit to the left compared to the next two lines (with the “15” and “23” footnotes). Is there some trick for that? Maybe the `\sbox0{\footnotemark}` should go into the `\makebox`?

Comment: Either bigfoot or manyfoot is doing weird things with the footnote mark.  The mark is SUPPOSED to be put in1o a 1.8em wide box, but instead it is now unboxed and preceded by some unknown space and glue.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found, after a lot of time spent looking at the `bigfoot` documentation (or rather implementation), is to redefine the `\@preparefnhtext` macro:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\textheight=.4\textheight

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}
\makeatletter  % To use the @ character in macro names
\let\@old@preparefnhtext=\@preparefnhtext
\FootnoteSpecific{default}\def\@preparefnhtext{\hfill\@old@preparefnhtext}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
All of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
all of the master recipes and most of the sub-recipes,\footnote{and sub-sub-recipes.}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

(The `\FootnoteSpecific{default}` is optional, but just good practice in case you have more than one footnote apparatus.)

---

This precisely answers your question (“How can I make the horizontal strechability between the footnotes infinite, so that they become evenly aligned at the right margin?”), but after looking at the output I wonder whether it's the best question to ask. I don't know a great solution for avoiding the awkward stretches on the last line, but I imagine that in practice you will be able to rewrite your footnotes if necessary to improve the appearance. Really, I'm not even sure I understand what I've done — the documentation of `\@preparefnhtext` says:

> This creates appropriate skips to be put before the horizontal material to make the indentation correct with a breakpoint before the footnote as well as when in run-in text. This is run once at the start of each horizontal mode footnote when it is first being typeset, in horizontal mode.

which is not really clear to me. Probably the better solution would be to typeset the “paragraph” containing all the footnotes to be right-justified, if that's possible.